# Is the combine_results method deprecated in qiskit v0.20.0

Tags: qiskit, programming

According to the [ManagedResults Documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.ibmq.managed.ManagedResults.html) the class has a `combine_results` method, however when attempting to use it as follows:

```
job_set = IBMQJobManager().run(circs, backend=ibmq_backend, name='job-set-abc')
job_results = job_set.results()
job_results_combined = job_results.combine_results() # fails on this line
job_counts_combined = job_results_combined.get_counts()
```

I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'ManagedResults' object has no attribute 'combine_results'

Furthermore, the `combine_results` method is not listed under `help(type(job_results))`:

Does this mean that the method has been deprecated? If so how can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still there. See the source code: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibmq-provider/blob/stable/0.8/qiskit/providers/ibmq/managed/managedresults.py#L178

Are you using the right version of `qiskit-ibmq-provider`? `combine_results` was introduced in 0.8.

If you do

```
import qiskit
print(qiskit.__qiskit_version__)
```

it'll show you the version of each element.

Comment: hmm, strange, I very recently upgraded to v0.20 but qiskit-ibmq-provider is still on 0.7.2

Comment: furthermore, when I execute in the anaconda prompt: pip show qiskit-ibmq-provider it shows v0.8, however when I start the python interpreter and run: qiskit.__qiskit_version__ I get v0.7.2, which is quite unexpected.